# How do I create a structure that can be used in a Rust multithreaded server?

Tags: multithreading, server, concurrency, rust

I want to implement a simple server, used by 3 different module of my project.
These modules will send data to the server, which will save it into a file and merge these informations when these modules will finish their job.
All these informations have a timestamp (a float) and a label (a float or a string).

This is my data structure to save these informations:

```
pub struct Data {
    file_name: String,
    logs: Vec<(f32, String)>,
    measures: Vec<(f32, f32)>,
    statements: Vec<(f32, String)>,
}
```

I use `socket` to interact with the server.

I use also `Arc` to implement a `Data` struct and make it shareable for each of these modules.
So, when I handle the client, I verify if the message sent by the module is correct, and if it is I call a new function that process and save the message in the good data structure field (`logs`,  `measures` or `statements`).

```
// Current ip address
let ip_addr: &str = &format!("{}:{}",
                             &ip,
                             port);

// Bind the current IP address
let listener = match TcpListener::bind(ip_addr) {
    Ok(listener) => listener,
    Err(error) => panic!("Canno't bind {}, due to error {}",
                         ip_addr,
                         error),
};

let global_data_struct = Data::new(DEFAULT_FILE.to_string());
let global_data_struct_shared = Arc::new(global_data_struct);

// Get and process streams
for stream in listener.incoming() {
    let mut global_data_struct_shared_clone = global_data_struct_shared.clone();
    thread::spawn(move || {
        // Borrow stream
        let stream = stream;
        match stream {
            // Get the stream value
            Ok(mut stream_v) => {
                let current_ip = stream_v.peer_addr().unwrap().ip();
                let current_port = stream_v.peer_addr().unwrap().port();
                println!("Connected with peer {}:{}", current_ip, current_port);
                // PROBLEM IN handle_client!
                // A get_mut from global_data_struct_shared_clone
                // returns to me None, not a value - so I
                // can't access to global_data_struct_shared_clone
                // fields :'(
                handle_client(&mut stream_v, &mut global_data_struct_shared_clone);
            },
            Err(_) => error!("Canno't decode stream"),
        }
    });
}

// Stop listening
drop(listener);
```

I have some problems to get a mutable reference in `handle_client` to process fields in `global_data_struct_shared_clone`, because the `Arc::get_mut(global_data_struct_shared_clone)` returns to me `None` - due to the `global_data_struct_shared.clone()` for each incoming request.

Can someone help me to manage correctly this structure between these 3 modules please?

Comment: Have you tried using a `Arc<Mutex<...>>` ?

Comment: No, because I think that I will got problems using `Mutex`, especially because no one of my module will access to a field that is already by a module. Each module has it own field in `Data` - so give `Mutex` to `Arc` will block uselessly my struct right...?

Comment: It only blocks while processing, but you can perfectly do it with more granularity :)

Comment: Ok, I will try it, thank you :-)
I will post the solution in if it works.

Comment: Ok so, I tried to use `Mutex` with `Arc` and it seems working!
Next level: granularity...
Thanks a lot again ;-)

Comment: To increase granularity, if `logs`, `measures` and `statements` can be updated independently, you can use one `Mutex` for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

The insight of Rust is that memory safety is achieved by enforcing **Aliasing XOR Mutability**.

Enforcing this single principle prevents whole classes of bugs: *pointer/iterator invalidation* (which was the goal) and also *data races*.

---

As much as possible, Rust will try to enforce this principle at compile-time; however it can also enforce it at run-time if the user opts in by using dedicated types/methods.

`Arc::get_mut` is such a method. An `Arc` (Atomic Reference Counted pointer) is specifically meant to share a reference between multiple owners, which means aliasing, and as a result disallows mutability by default; `Arc::get_mut` will perform a run-time check: if the pointer is actually not alias (count of 1), then it allows mutability.

However, as you realized, this is not suitable in your case since the `Arc` is aliased at that point in time.

---

So you need to turn to other types.

The simplest solution is `Arc<Mutex<...>>`, `Arc` allows sharing, `Mutex` allows controlled mutability, together you can share with run-time controlled mutability enforced by the `Mutex`.

This is coarse-grained, but might very well be sufficient.

More sophisticated approaches can use `RwLock` (Reader-Writer lock), more granular `Mutex` or even atomics; but I would advise starting with a single `Mutex` and see how it goes, you have to walk before you run.